# Unhandled event loop exception

Tags: java, eclipse

Fui atualizar o meu eclipse e estou usando a versão oxygen. Quando inicializo ou quando vou verificar se tem updates de pacotes aparece essa mensagem abaixo e meu tollbar não aparece. alguém tem a solução? poderia ajudar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Quando aparece essa mensagem de erro? geralmente é disparada por alguma ação.

Comment: Quando inicializo o eclipse ou quando verifico se quero fazer updates de pacotes

Comment: Coloca essa informação na pergunta e também a versão do eclipse. no `<<details` mostra algo mais?

Answer (score 1):

O problema era na pasta onde o eclipse estava instalada, pois não dava permissão de alteração. Alterei a permissão da pasta, atualizei os pacotes do eclipse e reiniciei. Problema resolvido!